# Resolve maven plugin issue: ' Unable to load mojo'

Tags: maven-2, maven, dependencies, maven-plugin, maven-dependency-plugin

I have configured all the dependencies in my `pom.xml` through maven. When i give the command `mvn install` I get the following error:

> [INFO] Internal error in the plugin manager executing goal
>   'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.4.3:test': Unable to
>   load the mojo
>   'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.4.3:test' in the
>   plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin'. A required
>   class is missing:
>   org/apache/maven/surefire/util/NestedCheckedException
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.util.NestedCheckedException

**How can I resolve this problem?**

Comment: Would you please past the pom here to be able to follow the explanation otherwise we could only take a look into our glass bulb...

Answer (score 25):

You appear to be experiencing this issue: [SUREFIRE-85](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-85).

The most likely cause appears to be corrupt jar files in your local repository. Try clearing out all maven jars from your local repository. Remove everything from `<your-home-directory>/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven` and run the build again.

Also, make sure you're using a stable, up-to-date version of Maven.

Comment: +1, had this problem and clearing out the local repository (in fact just deleting the "org" subdirectory) worked for me.

Comment: We had similar but not the same problem on our Jenkins CI server. Builds were fine (even with tests) but surfire reports failed with `InvocationTargetException` caused by `NoClassDefFoundError` caused by `ClassNotFoundException` this all ended after many more lines with `MojoExecutionException: Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log` -- cleaning `repository` on CI server indeed helped (cleaning just workspace of the project was not enough). Big thanks for this answer.

Comment: Thank you from the future. Just had this on a fresh maven enterprise project in netbeans and was mystified.

Answer (score 2):

I just had this issue and by deleting the org directory and rebuilding this solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
Using: Maven 3.0.5 required surefire:>2.10. 2.10 failed:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) on project robot-arm: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test: org/apache/maven/surefire/util/NestedCheckedException
```

**2.11** works.
**2.17** works.

Comment: Upgrading the maven to the latest version 3.10 didn't help, but @Kevin's answer helped me and worked.

Answer (score 1):

I got "unable to exe mojo" error when I build a maven project (JAVA), I noticed it also failed to get JAVA_HOME path which i added in my .batch_profile, manually export JAVA home problem resolved. it looks in many cases this build problem could happen but check system env variable might help ... David

Answer (score 0):

I solved upgrading the plug in version in my pom.xml **1.17 failed 1.30.1 OK**